# Material Design Button. Выделяемая область при нажатии на кнопку!

Tags: android, kotlin, button, material-design, android-on-click

Имеется два MaterialButton расположенных в CardView (LinearLayout). При нажатии на button выделяется не вся область, которая показана в designer при наведении на button (эта область отмечена красным прямоугольником на картинке). Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выделялась вся область, выделенная на button. Просто при нажатии на button между ними образуется некий образ, которого не должно быть. 
[image: MaterialButton click]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundSetting"
tools:context=".Settings">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/SettingButtons"
            android:text="@string/change_email">

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/SettingButtons"
            android:text="@string/change_password">

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

```
<style name="SettingButtons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:gravity">fill_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextSetting</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="iconTint">@color/colorTextSetting</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">end</item>
</style>
```

Comment: какие то margin/padding для кнопок указаны?

Comment: @pavlofff нет, ничего не указывал

Comment: Приложите разметку  даного экрана. Так будет проще разобраться, а не угадывать. И как создаете кардвью и элементы.

Comment: @V.March, закинул

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь в стиль две строчки. Это должно решить проблему

```
<item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
<item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
```

Comment: спасибо, проблему решило

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант разметки:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/SettingButtons"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/change_password">
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, ваш вариант не сработал у меня, мне помогло решение Nuclominus